# Avoid running a function multiple times in a query

Tags: azure-application-insights, ms-app-analytics

I have the following query in [Application Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-analytics-reference) where I run the [parsejson](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-analytics-reference#parsejson) function multiple times in the same query.

Is it possible to reuse the data from the `parsejson()` function after the first invocation? Right now I call it three times in the query. I am trying to see if calling it just once might be more efficient.

```
EventLogs
| where Timestamp > ago(1h)  
        and tostring(parsejson(tostring(Data.JsonLog)).LogId) =~ '567890'
|   project Timestamp, 
    fileSize = toint(parsejson(tostring(Data.JsonLog)).fileSize),  
    pageCount = tostring(parsejson(tostring(Data.JsonLog)).pageCount)
| limit 10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `extend` for that:

```
EventLogs
| where Timestamp > ago(1h)
| extend JsonLog = parsejson(tostring(Data.JsonLog)
| where tostring(JsonLog.LogId) =~ '567890'
|   project Timestamp, 
    fileSize = toint(JsonLog.fileSize),  
    pageCount = tostring(JsonLog.pageCount)
| limit 10
```